# Website Payments Standard: How would I connect the order being sent and the IPN receiving it?

Tags: html, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a custom shopping cart set up and I am wondering how I would connect the 'Order a client makes' in my database to the 'IPN POST' Paypal will send once the order is complete.

I could ask for an email address and compare the two; but they might not be the same. And what checks do I need to carry out at minimum when dealing with the `IPN handler`?

*I found a lot of this information spread out across multiple questions. I hope this saves others a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a `custom` variable hidden in your HTML along with your oder that will be passed back to the IPN once the order is completed.

---

**How to do this at the order stage for 'Website Payments Standards':**

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="UNIQUEVALUE">
```

UNIQUEVALUE is a unique identifier stored in your database to identify the order.

---

**At the completed payment stage:**

This will be passed to your IPN as the POST variable `custom`.

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/ipn/integration-guide/IPNReference#id091EAB0105Z
*Also states the max length of this custom variable is: 255 Characters.

---

**Before going live you should at minimum have the following checks:**

Check 1: Check Order Exists
Check 2: Check Order is not duplicate
Check 3: Check you are paid the right amount
Check 4: Test with Sandbox / Fake Orders
Check 5: Test, test and test again

---

*Check 1: Check Order Exists*

In your handler/listener IPN you should then query your database for this UNIQUEVALUE and if it is not found email yourself that this has happened.

---

*Check 2: Check Order is not duplicate*

You should store the 'txn_id' in your database alongside the state of the payment. If the order is complete, then this means the `txn_id` is a duplicate and should be handled as so.

*Remember: Check the state of the payment. This could come through as pending etc... if `txn_type = web_accept` and `payment_status = Completed` then the order is complete. This is why you need to store the status of the order. As you could get a pending order now and later a complete order. These will both have the same `txn_id`.

A full list of status' can be found here: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/ipn/integration-guide/IPNReference#id091EB04C0HS

For those lazy these can be: Canceled_Reversal / Completed / Created / Denied / Expired / Failed / Pending / Refunded / Reversed / Processed / Voided.

---

*Check 3: Check you are paid the right amount*

Another check you should do is to see if the payment received and the cost of the order are the same. With the 'Website Payments Standard' someone could alter your HTML code and pass through a different payment amount.

---

*Check 4: Test with Sandbox / Fake Orders*

Use https://developer.paypal.com/ go to 'Application' and send a test IPN Message to your IPN handler. And also remember to change in your code in your `IPN handler` to `sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr` from `paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr`. Otherwise this will fail.

---

***Check 5: Test, test and test again***

Using the paypal 'send a test IPN Message', test your `IPN handler` thoroughly. And then test it again.